# OIDC and SSM in a Single Github Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, openid-connect, aws-ssm

actually i created a Github Action, which used OIDC to connect Github to AWS CLI, and then launched an EC2 Instance with an IAM Role attached just to establish an SSM Connection to Instance, now as you might have judged that there are 2 roles now in a single Github Action.
So when OIDC is connected, i get access to AWSCLI, but then when i run the instance with an IAM Role attached, this role over-rides the OIDC Role and hence running command "aws run instance" throws an error saying that i am not authorised to perform this operation because now i have my OIDC connection over-ridden.

Any potential way out!?

actually i created a Github Action, which used OIDC to connect Github to AWS CLI, and then launched an EC2 Instance with an IAM Role attached just to establish an SSM Connection to Instance, now as you might have judged that there are 2 roles now in a single Github Action.
So when OIDC is connected, i get access to AWSCLI, but then when i run the instance with an IAM Role attached, this role over-rides the OIDC Role and hence running command "aws run instance" throws an error saying that i am not authorised to perform this operation because now i have my OIDC connection over-ridden.